# HttpListener Crashes in Release mode

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, httplistener

To recreate the issue
1. Create a Android application
2. Install Nito.AsyncEx.Context
3. Add the code below
4. Set release mode
5. Deploy code
6. Start the app (and watch it burn! it crashes on both my `10.1" Marshmallow...` emulator and a `Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1`)

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using Nito.AsyncEx;

namespace App1
{
    [Activity(Label = "App1", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        private readonly HttpListener listener = new HttpListener();

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
            var thread = new System.Threading.Thread(RunThread);
            thread.Start();
        }

        void RunThread()
        {
            AsyncContext.Run(() => Run()); //Exception in release mode
            //Task.Run(Run); //Silent exception in release mode
        }

        protected async Task Run()
        {
            listener.Prefixes.Add("http://localhost:8082/");
            listener.Start();
            while (true)
            {
                var context = await listener.GetContextAsync();
                var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("<html><body>Hello world</body></html>");
                context.Response.OutputStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                context.Response.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following exception:

```
E/mono    (29964): Unhandled Exception:
E/mono    (29964): System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): mono-io-layer-error (10013)
E/mono    (29964):   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket..ctor (System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily addressFamily, System.Net.Sockets.SocketType socketType, System.Net.Sockets.ProtocolType protocolType) [0x00069] in <12894373fb4d403880bd3e387a4ef038>:0
E/mono    (29964):   at System.Net.EndPointListener..ctor (System.Net.HttpListener listener, System.Net.IPAddress addr, System.Int32 port, System.Boolean secure) [0x0003b] in <12894373fb4d403880bd3e387a4ef038>:0
E/mono    (29964):   at System.Net.EndPointManager.GetEPListener (System.String host, System.Int32 port, System.Net.HttpListener listener, System.Boolean secure) [0x0009d] in <12894373fb4d403880bd3e387a4ef038>:0
E/mono    (29964):   at System.Net.EndPointManager.AddPrefixInternal (System.String p, System.Net.HttpListener listener) [0x0005e] in <12894373fb4d403880bd3e387a4ef038>:0
E/mono    (29964):   at System.Net.EndPointManager.AddListener (System.Net.HttpListener listener) [0x0009c] in <12894373fb4d403880bd3e387a4ef038>:0
E/mono    (29964):   at System.Net.HttpListener.Start () [0x0000f] in <12894373fb4d403880bd3e387a4ef038>:0
...
```

Comment: Try to get the actual exception message, wrap the run code in a try/catch and see what it's telling you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To open a socket, your application needs the [INTERNET](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#INTERNET) permission. Add the following line to your `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: It's because it's added automatically in debug mode 